# Xcode 8.3.3 - Not allowing to connect IBOutlet to the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I realised that my maps app was not connected to the new storyboard. I have tried everything (to my knowledge) and have just about run out of ideas.

[image: In this picture it shows that I can't connect the 2]

And yes I have changed the class in the storyboard to the map controller that I am trying to connect it to.

Comment: When you click on the highlighted blue book icon along the top row of the right pane and change it to "Automatic", does the file that you want it to be connected to still come up as an option?

Comment: First check is your view class is FirstViewController? If yes then try to connect from left panel (where yourview structure is) to the IBOutlet in code

Comment: Hey Michael, when i click automatic it just says "no assistant results".

Comment: korgx9, how do i check my view class?

Comment: Slight off topic, but XCode 9 would be out in a day or two and iTunes doesn't accept submissions from old XCodes when the new version arrives. Maybe you can check this with a fresh eye in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect objects to already existing outlets you need to mouseover the variable name instead of the gutter.

Like so:
[image: IBOutlet Mouseover variable]

Answer (score 1):

please check your class name in "show the identity inspector" panel as in following image.

[image]