# How can I connect two segment controls to each other?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: two segmented controls]

I'm trying to disable the bottom segment control if the user clicks Diesel. The problem is I can't connect two `IBAction`s to each other. Such as:

```
@IBAction func didSelect(_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch control.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        isPetrol = true
        isDiesel = false

    case 1:
        isPetrol = false
        isDiesel = true

    default:
        print  ("break")
    }
}

@IBACtion func didSecondSelect (_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
    //something here that when case1 is clicked disables it
    }
}
```

How can I disable it if the top case 1 is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `IBAction`s and `IBOutlet`s.

You should create an `IBOutlet` that points to the second segmented control and change that from the first one's code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var secondSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func didSelect(_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
    [...]

    secondSegmentedControl.isEnabled = control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
}
```

For more information about working with `IBOutlet`s, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46270740/3151675).